# Plotting multiple logistic curves using mapply

Tags: r, plot, regression

I have a set of 20 intercepts and coefficients for a logistic regression model. I'd like to plot them all on one graph (ideally, with base and not ggplot). I plot a single curve like this:

```
x = datapoints
curve(plogis(intercept + coef*x), min(x), max(x), add=TRUE)
```

To do this with a linear model, I can use `mapply`:

```
a = intercepts
b = coefs
mapply(abline, a,b)
```

Is there a way to use `mapply` or something similar with `curve` and `plogis` to avoid using a loop?

Comment: Construct a relevant test case. Your current request implies the need for multiple datasets, so I suggest building at least three (but NOT 20).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a reproducible example, but this is a proof of concept:

```
x = runif(20)/2
plot(x, bty="l", ylim=c(0,1))

a = runif(20)/100
b = runif(20)/4
my.func <-function(intercept,coefs) curve(plogis(intercept+coefs*x), add=TRUE)
mapply(my.func,a,b)
```

[image]